# CSS animations fadeIn doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to applicate on my webpage a fade in effect on the content of my webpage but instead of getting the fade in effect my content is just "hiding".

This is the CSS I'm using:

```
/* make keyframes that tell the start state and the end state of our object */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0 !important; } to { opacity:1 !important; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0 !important;  } to { opacity:1 !important; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0 !important; } to { opacity:1 !important; } }


fadeIn

.fade-in {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1 ;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1 ;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;

    -webkit-animation-duration:1s ;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s ;
    animation-duration:1s ;
}

.fade-in.one {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s ;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.7s ;
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
```

For this piece of html:

```
<div data-role="content" id="contenidoHistoria" class="fade-in one">

        <p>Entre los melismas sonoros del rebalaje y las intrincadas calles del antiguo barrio del Perchel, y a la sombra espiritual de su Iglesia parroquial del Carmen, surgi&oacute en el a&ntilde;o 2005 el sue&ntilde;o colectivo de un grupo de j&oacutevenes de aquel barrio, que bajo el &aacutenimo y el empuje del entonces p&aacuterroco nuestro querido Manolo Segura- se propusieron poner en marcha la hoy conocida como Banda de Cornetas y Tambores de Nuestra Se&ntilde;ora del Carmen del Perchel-M&aacutelaga.</p>

    </div><!-- /content -->
</div>
```

If I set opacity as NOT 0 on ".fade-in {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */" I can see the content, but of course that's not what I'm looking for.

Regards.

Comment: please share your code in a fiddle along with the script

Comment: Jquery has in built fadein effect. U don't really need all that css.   --- http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp

Comment: I'm developing for phonegap on IOS, If I use jquery fade in effect, the screen makes a "blink" effect, that's why I want to do it with css3.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `!important` from your animation properties. (And also remove the "fadeIn" just below your keyframe declaration.)

Here's a working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/x62pU/2/

I also edited the shorthand of the animation declaration to decrease your code.

Comment: Hi Leon thank you very much for your answer, but It's not working for example in my case for Safari I guess, I'm still getting the content hide without the fade animation

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I edited the shorthand for the animation slightly, and I forgot that Firefox interprets the shorthand slightly different. Here's a working version for Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/x62pU/2/

Comment: Leon, I'm using it on chrome for example to test my iphone app developed on phonegap (jquery, etc) but I can't get it to work either

Comment: The jsFiddle link I provided is working for me in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. It's also working on my iPhone. Are you testing my link or your own code? If so, could you provide a fiddle of the code you're testing?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work in firefox, chrome and safari. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZP565/2/) link.

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity:0; } 100% { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity:0; } 100% { opacity:1; } }
.fade-in {
    opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
    animation: fadeIn  1s  ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
.fade-in.one {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
```

Hope this helps!